# Failing to update primary_sale_happened on an NFT via token account in anchor program

Tags: anchor, metaplex, rust, nft, metadata

I'm currently developing an escrowed NFT sale contract and when I try to update the `primary_sale_happened` field of an NFT, after paying the creators and right before transferring it, I get this error `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing`.

I know it comes from this function call because commenting it removes the error.

```
pub const VAULT_AUTHORITY_PREFIX: &[u8] = b"VAULT_AUTHORITY";

// [...]

let (_vault_authority, vault_authority_bump) =
    Pubkey::find_program_address(&[VAULT_AUTHORITY_PREFIX], &id());
let authority_seeds = &[&VAULT_AUTHORITY_PREFIX[..], &[vault_authority_bump]];

// [...]

mpl_update_primary_sale_happened_via_token(
    &self.metadata.to_account_info(),
    &self.vault_authority.to_account_info(),
    &self.vault_account.to_account_info(),
    authority_seeds,
)?;
```

Here is its definition (copied from [metaplex/fixed-price-sale](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/656188a5322236c0bcb69ed676a2150fa872e595/fixed-price-sale/program/src/utils.rs#L184)):

```
#[inline(always)]
pub fn mpl_update_primary_sale_happened_via_token<'a>(
    metadata: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    owner: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    token: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    signers_seeds: &[&[u8]],
) -> Result<()> {
    let tx = mpl_token_metadata::instruction::update_primary_sale_happened_via_token(
        mpl_token_metadata::id(),
        metadata.key(),
        owner.key(),
        token.key(),
    );

    invoke_signed(
        &tx,
        &[metadata.clone(), owner.clone(), token.clone()],
        &[&signers_seeds],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

And here is the Context:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(price: u64)]
pub struct Buy<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: Not dangerous. Account seeds and owner checked in constraint.
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            mpl_token_metadata::state::PREFIX.as_bytes(),
            mpl_token_metadata::id().as_ref(),
            mint.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump,
        seeds::program = mpl_token_metadata::id(),
        constraint = !metadata.data_is_empty(),
        constraint = metadata.owner == &mpl_token_metadata::id(),
    )]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub seller: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [Sale::PREFIX.as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = seller,
        has_one = mint,
        constraint = price == sale.price,
        close = seller
    )]
    pub sale: Account<'info, Sale>,

    #[account(
        mut, 
        seeds = [VAULT_PREFIX.as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = vault_authority,
    )]
    pub vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
     #[account(
        seeds = [VAULT_AUTHORITY_PREFIX.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub vault_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

I'm pretty confident (but cannot be 100% sure) that the arguments are valid since I can read the metadata (so the Metadata account seems okay) and later on transfer the NFT from `vault_account` whose owner is `vault_authority` (so they must be valid too...).

I'm also wondering if the issue could come from my local-validator ? I started it with a dump of metaplex's `token-metadata` program and the other functionalities seem to work juste fine... (using this command `solana-test-validator --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s dumps/metadata.so --reset`)

Does anyone know how to fix this error please ?

Comment: Also I have since then changed the way I retrieve the `vault_authority_bump` using `ctx.bumps`, making it kinda better computationally wise but does not fix my issue in any way

Comment: are you still stuck with this issue ser ?